# How to apply text rotation in CSS?

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve the below

[image]

This is what I have achieved so far

[image]

by using the below CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    width: 90px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
    /* Rotate div */   
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div><font color="red"><b>ACTIVE</b></font></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am looking for the text rotation. How can I achieve the same?

Comment: Can't you just rotate by 90deg?

Comment: FYI <font> is deprecated in HTML5. And I'm sure if you you do 90deg you'll get the result you're after.

Comment: @priyankasarkar Do you want to rotate the entire div or just the text? Please be clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the value of `transform: rotate(270deg)` to `transform: rotate(90deg)` , then add `transform-origin` property for set a rotated element's base placement.

```
div {
    width: 90px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
    /* Rotate div */   
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: left;
}
```

It's no style for text rotation

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS3 @keyframes animation to get after it. Check this snippet:

```css
div {
    width: 90px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
    /* Rotate div */   
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    position:relative;
    top:40px;
}
b{ 
  position:absolute;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-animation: rotate 3s; 
  -moz-animation: rotate 3s; 
  animation: rotate 3s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0%   {transform: rotate(360deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(180deg);}
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
    0%   {transform: rotate(360deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(180deg);}
}

@keyframes rotate {
    0%   {transform: rotate(360deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(180deg);}
}
```

```html
<div><font color="red"><b>ACTIVE</b></font></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rotating your div, rotate your `<b> tag` and try,

```css
div {
    width: 20px;
    height: 110px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display:block;
    color:red;
    padding-top:40px;
  }
div > b{
   transform: rotate(-270deg);
   display:block;
   }
```

```html
<div><b>ACTIVE</b></div>
```